# Accessing OneDrive from Desktop App

Tags: c#, onedrive

I'm trying to get to grips with OneDrive, using this tutorial:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh826529.aspx

When I run in code, it gets as far as the makeAccessTokenRequest function, sending the following requestURL:

"https: //login.live.com/oauth20_token.srf?client_id=[myclientID] &client_secret=[myclientsecret]&redirect_uri=https:// login.live.com/oauth20_desktop.srf&grant_type=authorization_code&code=[authcode]"

(please ignore the spaces after "https:", I had to add them here to allow the question)

[myclientid], [myclientsecret], and [authcode] all appear to be populated correctly.  It seems to get a response, as it runs the function "accessToken_DownloadStringCompleted", but throws a "TargetInvocationException" error,  The inner message of the error is ""The remote server returned an error: (400) Bad Request.".

Could anyone throw any light on this?  I'm completely new to this, so apologies if my question makes no sense, or is irritatingly vague..

Answer (score 0):

Requests to the oauth20_token.srf end point need to be a POST with the parameters in the body of the post, instead of the query string. Since you didn't mention what code you're using to build the HTTP request it's hard to provide an example, but take a look at [RedeemAuthorizationCodeAsync](https://github.com/rgregg/microsoft-account-winforms/blob/master/MicrosoftAccount.WindowsForms/MicrosoftAccountOAuth.cs#L90) in my sample OAuth 2 project for an idea.

The outgoing request should look like this:

```
POST https://login.live.com/oauth20_token.srf
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded

client_id={client_id}&redirect_uri={redirect_uri}&client_secret={client_secret}&code={code}&grant_type=authorization_code
```

You may also find this tutorial easier to follow than the one you linked with: https://dev.onedrive.com/auth/msa_oauth.htm.

If you are doing something with OneDrive (you tagged the post OneDrive) then you may want to consider using the [OneDrive SDK](https://github.com/onedrive/onedrive-sdk-csharp) instead. It includes authentication for several types of .NET projects so you don't need to figure out how to do auth yourself.

Comment: Thanks so much for your help, I really appreciate it.  I tried again using your library,  It all runs fine until it runs:

LoginAuthorizationCodeFlowAsync()

It calls RedeemAuthorizationCodeAsync(), which seems to build the query with the correct clientid, clientsecret and auth code.  But it returns null to "tokens".

Could this be to do with the way the app is registered with OneDrive?  It doesn't list a platform on the application page, but whenever I try to add a "web" platform, it simply saves without any platform again..

Thanks once again for your help.